# Type "ping" in network tab

Tags: google-chrome, http, ping

When consulting network tabs I saw some Google analytics calls:
[image]

Some have the type "ping".
I know the [ping attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) but it's when a link is clicked and the payload is "PING".

Here I didn't click on anything and the payload is not "PING" (it contains some info for analytics).

The response content/type is "plain/text".

The question *[What is text/ping and is this a new standard? Is it browser dependent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971923/what-is-text-ping-and-is-this-a-new-standard-is-it-browser-dependent)* looks like the same but in that case it has the "PING" payload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requests whose `type` show up as `ping` in Chrome network tab are those that are sent using [`navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon).

> It's intended to be used for sending analytics data to a web server,
> and avoids some of the problems with legacy techniques for sending
> analytics, such as the use of `XMLHttpRequest`.